# Why does my fetch fail on my server but not on local host? And array.slice breaks fetch as well

Tags: javascript, fetch, slice

I have a piece of javascript that is supposed to get a JSON file full of questions and then save those questions to localstorage. However, when I move the project to my LAMP server fetch stops working.

```
$('#start_exam').click(function(){
    
    // Get # of questions and set localstorage
    var nrOfQuestions = $("#nrOfQuestions").val();
    localStorage.setItem("nrOfQuestions", nrOfQuestions);
    
    // Set initial localstorage values
    localStorage.setItem("passed", 0);
    localStorage.setItem("failed", 0);
    localStorage.setItem("index", 1);
    
    // Fetch questions, randomize, and load into localstorage
    fetch('/data/questions.json');
    fetch('/data/questions.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((loadedQuestions) => {
            //console.log('Output: ', loadedQuestions);
            var questions = shuffle(loadedQuestions);
            //questions = questions.slice(0, nrOfQuestions);
            localStorage.setItem('questions', JSON.stringify(questions));
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
        })
    ;
    
    // Shuffle questions in the array
    function shuffle(sourceArray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.length - 1; i++) {
            var j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (sourceArray.length - i));
            var temp = sourceArray[j];
            sourceArray[j] = sourceArray[i];
            sourceArray[i] = temp;
        }
        return sourceArray;
    }
    
    // Redirect
    window.location.href = "/test.html";
    
});
```

I managed to get it working again by adding `fetch('/data/questions.json');` before the fetch that had previously worked on my local machine. BUT i'm not at all sure why this works and it doesn't follow the correct syntax at all. The error is:

```
Fetch failed loading: GET 'url'
```

I also had to comment out the line that slices my array to make it shorter before committing to local storage: `//questions = questions.slice(0, nrOfQuestions);`. If I uncomment that line of code I get an error that reads `array.slice is not a function`

Anyone have any ideas? Both of these problems have only occured on my server.

Am I missing something in htaccess? Do I need to install server side nodejs?? I have no clue.

Comment: Adding `fetch('/data/questions.json');` by itself makes no sense. Why are you doing `window.location.href = "/test.html";` that is going to cause the page to reload and the fetch calls that are active will be exited....

Comment: are you trying to read json file stored within your project? if yes, fetch('/data/questions.json') does not make sense

Comment: Please add the exact error messages you are getting. It is unlikely that code using `questions.slice` would throw an error that says `array.slice is not a function`. Also, fetch would throw an error if the URL it was asked to get was `'url'`, since that is not a valid URL.

Comment: Thank you epascarllo, you're suggestion about the page reloading and the active fetch calls exiting was my issue

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just reloading the page before the fetch was finished running... I'm not completely sure why it was working on the localhost but not on the server though. Maybe fetch took longer to retrieve the file on the server than it did on my machine?

All I did was move the window redirect inside the array. Thanks to [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) for helping me see my newbie mistake.

Either way, this is the code I have now - and its working just fine:

```
$('#start_exam').click(function(){
    
    // Get # of questions and set localstorage
    var nrOfQuestions = $("#nrOfQuestions").val();
    localStorage.setItem("nrOfQuestions", nrOfQuestions);
    
    // Set initial localstorage values
    localStorage.setItem("passed", 0);
    localStorage.setItem("failed", 0);
    localStorage.setItem("index", 1);
    localStorage.removeItem("questions");
    
    // Fetch questions, randomize, and load into localstorage
    fetch('/data/questions.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((loadedQuestions) => {
            //console.log('Output: ', loadedQuestions);
            var questions = shuffle(loadedQuestions);
            questions = questions.slice(0, nrOfQuestions);
            localStorage.setItem('questions', JSON.stringify(questions));
            // Redirect
            window.location.href = "/test.html";
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Fetch Error:', err);
        })
    ;
    
    // Shuffle questions in the array
    function shuffle(sourceArray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.length - 1; i++) {
            var j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (sourceArray.length - i));
            var temp = sourceArray[j];
            sourceArray[j] = sourceArray[i];
            sourceArray[i] = temp;
        }
        return sourceArray;
    }
        
});
```

I'm not sure why the extra line seemed to something - It eventually stopped working.